# OpenSSL - SSL Server Certificate signing

Tags: openssl, base64

I've just started to learn OpenSSL at University and currently I am learning the basics of signing certificates. I don't want to paste the question here as I'd like to learn about it rather than just get the answer.

I have been given an RSA Private key for use in an SSLserver certificate. My task is to use this key to sign and base64 encode a single word.

I did think the command was:

openssl rsautl -sign -inkey Q4.txt -in plain | openssl base64

But that appears to be incorrect.

I'm just wondering if anyone can tell me if I'm on the right track? and where I should be looking.

Thanks

Comment: `plain` is your input file, containing a single word (without carriage returns and line feeds)? `Q4.txt` is your private key (in PEM format)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply to this post. It turned out there was a $ on the end of vampire that could only be seen when using the cat function. So once removed it worked. Thanks for your help.